# Batch - Inverse/Negative FOR loops?

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, inverse

I'm trying to concatenate many files into two individual files.

The first file will be a concatenation of all other files with "bob" in the filename. The second file will be a concatenation of all files WITHOUT "bob" in the filename. Both files will output the name of the file before actually doing the concatenation.

Here's what I have so far:

```
            @echo off
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set bob=All_bob.txt
            set jimmy=All_jimmy.txt

            if exist %bob% del %bob%
            if exist %jimmy% del %jimmy%

            for %%a in (*bob*.txt) do (
            echo /* >>%bob%
            echo * %%a >>%bob%
            echo */ >>%bob%
            copy/b %bob%+"%%a" %bob%
            echo. >>%bob%
            echo. >>%bob%)


            for %%a not in (*bob*.txt) do (
            echo /* >>%jimmy%
            echo * %%a >>%jimmy%
            echo */ >>%jimmy%
            copy/b %jimmy%+"%%a" %jimmy%
            echo. >>%jimmy%
            echo. >>%jimmy%)
```

However, the second FOR loop (at the bottom) doesn't want to play nice using "not", and using an exclamation point like this...

```
            for %%a !(*bob*.txt) do (
```

...doesn't want to work, either. So how do I concatenate files that do NOT contain what is inside the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clean solution to this.

You could probably use FINDSTR to filter %%a but that would require turning `*bob*.txt` into a regular expression and that is probably not easy to automate.

Another (ugly) solution is to use nested loops:

```
echo bob:
for %%a in (*bob*.txt) do (
    echo %%a
)

echo not bob:
for %%a in (*) do (
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&set inc=1
    for %%b in (*bob*.txt) do if "%%~a"=="%%~b" set inc=0
    if "!inc!"=="1" echo %%a
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using find:

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
echo %%a | find /V "bob")
```

This should return all .txt files that don't have "bob" in them.

Comment: This works fine for this specific example, but what if the search string is foo*bar*baz.txt or b?b.txt

Comment: @Anders, likso answers OP question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `findstr` and a regular expression for `*bob*.txt`:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir /b ^| findstr ".*bob.*\.txt"`) do (…)
```

Just use the `/V` switch to process all other files:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir /b ^| findstr /v ".*bob.*\.txt"`) do (…)
```

You can use the `help` command or the `/?` switch for `for` or `findstr` for more information.
I cleared the delimiters (`delims=`) to allow for spaces in the filenames.

Comment: Just use the patterns `foo.*bar.*baz\.txt` or `b.b\.txt` to match file search `foo*bar*baz.txt` or `b?b.txt` :]